# Выбор всех тегов начиная с тега с конкретным ID

Tags: javascript, dom

Можно ли выбрать все теги до конца родительского блока начиная с блока с конкретным ID?

Пример:

```
<div>
    <custom-tag id="a">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="b">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="c">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="d">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="e">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="f">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
    <custom-tag id="g">
        <custom-tag2>
        </custom-tag2>
    </custom-tag>
</div>
```

Нужно получить список объектов custom-tag после объекта с идентификатором "c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно

```js
 let id = 'c',
     list = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id}, #${id} ~ *`);
```